# Construct typed dictionary using swift

Tags: ios, swift

I would like to create a typed map (Dictionary) class to meet the following requirements:

```
func testMap() {
        var map = ActivitiesMap()
        var activity = Activity()
        activity.title = "Activity 1"
        activity.uuid = "asdf1234"
        map[activity.uuid] = activity

        for (key, mapActivity) in map {
            logger.debug("ACTIVITY MAP: \(key)=\(mapActivity)")
        }
    }
```

In short, I want this class to both be a dictionary such that it can be used in the for loop, however I want to ensure the keys are strings and the values are Activity objects.

I tried many variations of inheriting from Dictionary or typing the class, but so far it's resulted in multiple errors.

EDIT:
I don't think a simple generic dictionary will work, such as String:Activity. I want to have extra methods in the ActivityMap class, such as getAllActivitiesBetweenDates().

I need an actual class definition, not a generic dictionary expression.

Comment: What's wrong with a plain old `Dictionary<Key, Activity>`

Comment: I don't want to extend it, because all Dictionaries will get that extension. And I cannot use it in class inheritance in any way I could find.

Comment: It seems from the implementation of subscript and sequence it would be possible to use this as a dictionary-like object. Still working on it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make it looks like dictionary by implement subscript operator

And conform to `Sequence` protocol to support `for-in` loop

```
struct ActivitiesMap : Sequence {
    var map = [String:Activity]()

    subscript(key: String) -> Activity? {
    get {
        return map[key]
    }
    set(newValue) {
        map[key] = newValue
    }
    }

    func generate() -> GeneratorOf<(String, Activity)> {
        var gen = map.generate()
        return GeneratorOf() {
            return gen.next()
        }
    }

    // I can't find out type of map.generator() now, if you know it, you can do
    //func generate() -> /*type of map.generator()*/ {
    //    return map.generate();
    //}

}
```

Comment: I did that... and actually trying that in a loop directly seems I need to implement the Sequence protocol... so I'm getting closer. That class you defined won't work in a for loop as it is.

Comment: Such implementation requires a lot of delegation with code that just pass function invocations.

Comment: Trying the sequence implementation now.

Comment: @Keenle Yes. What is the problem?

Comment: I lot of code to pass function invocation. Not elegant solution.

Comment: @Keenle You don't need delegation method for all dictionary methods. only the one needed.

Comment: @Bryan getting an error on "var gen = map.generator()". Error is: "[String : Activity]' does not have a member named 'generator'"

Comment: @LeifAshley typo... should be `var gen = map.generate()`

Comment: Still an error on "return gen.next()": '(String, Activity)' is not identical to 'Activity'"

Comment: Ah so that's how it's done... return a tuple type. Bad ass sir. It works. :)

Answer (score 0):

This works for me. Not sure what is in your ActivitiesMap class, but just typed a Dictionary

```
class Activity{
    var title:String = "";
    var uuid: String = "";

}

func testMap() {
    //var map = ActivitiesMap()
    var map: Dictionary< String, Activity> = Dictionary< String, Activity>();
    var activity = Activity()
    activity.title = "Activity 1"
    activity.uuid = "asdf1234"
    map[activity.uuid] = activity

    for (key, mapActivity) in map {
        println("ACTIVITY MAP: \(key)=\(mapActivity)")
    }
}

testMap();
```

This is my output:

```
ACTIVITY MAP: asdf1234=C11lldb_expr_08Activity (has 2 children)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `typealias` keyword to define nice name of any type.

Here is how it can be used for your code:

```
class Activity { /* your code */ }
typealias ActivityMap = Dictionary<String, Activity>

var activityDict = ActivityMap()
```

And to support custom functions you can write an extension, example bellow:

```
extension Dictionary {
    func getAllActivitiesBetweenDates(fromDate:NSDate, toDate:NSDate) -> Array<Activity>
        // your code
        return []
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
let matchedActivities = activityDict.getAllActivitiesBetweenDates(/*date*/, /*date*/)
```

Comment: Ok this is close... but I actually want to add custom functions to the ActivityMap, e.g. getAllActivitiesBetweenDates(start, end)

Comment: So write an extension.

Comment: Would the extension modify all Dictionary structures or just the ActivityMap? The way I understand type alias is that if I extend the ActivityMap all Dictionaries will get that extension as well... or is that not the case?

Comment: Added example with `extension`. Let me know if it can work for you?

Comment: Then write a generic function at the top level that handles this.  From the name, it sounds like you could express it as a filter().

Answer (score 0):

```
class Activity {
    var title=""
    var id=""
    init(id:String, title:String) { self.id=id; self.title = title }
}



var activities = [String:Activity]()
let a1 = Activity(id:"a1", title:"title1")
let a2 = Activity(id:"a2", title:"title2")
let a3 = Activity(id:"a3", title:"title3")
activities[a1.id] = a1
activities[a2.id] = a2
activities[a3.id] = a3

for (id,activity) in activities {
    println("id: \(id) - \(activity.title)")
}
```

should print

```
id: a2 - title2
id: a3 - title3
id: a1 - title1
```

(key order not guaranteed to be the same)